# "Wrong number of args for this type of survival data" when coding a survival object in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, weibull

I'm experiencing the above error message when trying to run a survival analysis with Weibull distribution, in R.

My data is a bit tricky in that it contains both left and right censored observations.

I followed instructions found on https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/Surv.html:

"Interval censored data can be represented in two ways. For the first use type = "interval" and the codes shown above. In that usage the value of the time2 argument is ignored unless event=3. The second approach is to think of each observation as a time interval with (-infinity, t) for left censored, (t, infinity) for right censored, (t,t) for exact and (t1, t2) for an interval. This is the approach used for type = interval2. Infinite values can be represented either by actual infinity (Inf) or NA. The second form has proven to be the more useful one."

I decided to follow the second form, and coded my data with the following headings:

t1, t2 (start and end times), status (0,1,2), factor1, factor2

To run my model I write in R:

```
    model1 <- survreg(Surv(t1, t2, status, type='interval2')~factor(factor1) + factor(factor2), dist='weibull', data=data)
```

However, it is consistently giving me the error message:

```
    Error in Surv(paduration, status, type = "interval") : Wrong number of args for this type of survival data
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, as there are only 5 possible arguments for surv() objects, and the origin argument is irrelevant to my case. when I tried to use less argument, it still gives me the same error message. I've tried to do
        "type=interval"
instead but still get the same error message.

Please help.

Comment: I don't see how we can give you any advice when you don't include data and code.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. my code (the part that I'm having trouble with anyway) is really just that one line there. I've actually figured it out: apparently when you do type='interval2' you don't need the status statement, hence the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: t1 can't be zero, that's the problem. Don't feel like explaining. Posting here if someone stumbles upon this